# Alert box showing before function

Tags: javascript, html, function, alert

The alert box is displaying before the value is inputted in the second input box, but I have written the alert code after the input function. Can someone guide me how to make alert after input value.

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="que">
    <input type="text" id="ans">
    <input type="button" onclick="addd()" value="a">
<script>
function addd(){
  question = document.getElementById("que").value;
  document.getElementById("ans").value = question;
  alert(question);
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not in firefox - but anyway ... some browsers will do that ... try `setTimeout(() => alert(question))` instead - it has do with when rendering happens

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/478gaqrd/ cant reproduce the problem in Chrome

Comment: @JerwinMathewAton - you sure? Chrome (Windows) does display the alert BEFORE updating the `ans` input

Answer (score 0):

Adding alert function is setTimeout() worked for me.

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="que">
        <input type="text" id="ans">
        <input type="button" onclick="addd()" value="a">
    <script>
    function addd(){
      question = document.getElementById("que").value;
      document.getElementById("ans").value = question;
      setTimeout(() => alert(question));
    };
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```